# Easily show rows that are different among multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Imagine you have several tables with same structure (each table, one year of data):

table `states_2017`

```
stateID propertyID  owner         area  timestampGot
1       1           David Smith   15    123456789
2       2           Amanda Green  74    123456799
3       1           David Smith   15    123456999
```

table `states_2018`

```
stateID propertyID  owner          area timestampGot
1       3           Amanda Green   12   123459999
2       1           Peter Black    11   123499999
3       4           Jack Stone     62   123999999
4       2           Amanda Green   70   129999999
```

Then you have table properties with basic information about properties:

table `properties`

```
propertyID  defaultStateID  defaultStateYear
1           1               2017
2           2               2017
3           1               2018
4           3               2018
```

In the example above, state of propertyID 1 changed from its default state (stateID 1 in states_2017) to the most recent state (stateID 2 in states_2018). Similarly, state of propertyID 2 changed. How to show these changes (using MySQL)?

Desired output:

```
propertyID  owner         area  timestampGot
1           David Smith   15    123456789
1           Peter Black   11    123499999
2           Amanda Green  74    123456799
2           Amanda Green  70    129999999
```

Comment: Why isn't the (intermediate state for property 2) in the results? (`3       1           David Smith   15    123456999`)

Comment: The goal is to show the difference between the original and the most recent state. That's why any state in between is omitted.

Comment: I noted similar question which is actually aiming at showing rows that are different between two tables. As in my case multiple tables are involved (many states_year tables), I am not able to use that solution

Comment: It would be easier if you had a single table and not one per year.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Isn't it a good practice to avoid creation of one big slow-to-search table?

Comment: Big? How big? And "slow to search"? Why would it be slow to search? That's what indexes are for.

Answer (score 1):

The wanted query is not trivial at all but it would be a bit easier to write if there was one table and not one per year. So let's create a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW states AS
    SELECT stateID, propertyID, owner, area, timestampGot, 2010 AS year
    FROM states_2010
    UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT stateID, propertyID, owner, area, timestampGot, 2017
    FROM states_2017
    UNION ALL
    SELECT stateID, propertyID, owner, area, timestampGot, 2018
    FROM states_2018
    ... ;
```

Then, I assume that you want to get data from the earliest and the latest date per product. So we can use one of the (many) ways to get a greatest-n-per-group result (applied twice, one for the earliest date and another for the latest):

```
select 
    p.propertyid,
    s.owner,
    s.area,
    s.timestampgot,
    s.stateid
from properties as p
  left join states as s                    -- earliest timestamp
  on  s.propertyid = p.propertyid          -- for this property
  and (s.year, s.timestampgot) =
      ( select si.year, si.timestampgot
        from states as si
        where si.propertyid = p.propertyid
        order by si.year, si.timestampgot
        limit 1
      )
union all
select 
    p.propertyid,
    s.owner,
    s.area,
    s.timestampgot,
    s.stateid
from properties as p
  left join states as s                    -- latest timestamp
  on  s.propertyid = p.propertyid
  and (s.year, s.timestampgot) =
      ( select si.year, si.timestampgot
        from states as si
        where si.propertyid = p.propertyid
        order by si.year desc, si.timestampgot desc
        limit 1
      ) ;
```

Comment: Actually, I want to get data from the default state (not from the earliest) and the latest date. Default state may not be the earliest. It is specified in table properties by defaultStateID and defaultStateYear (see the original post). So for propertyID 1 where defaultStateID is 1 and defaultStateYear is 2017, default state is stateID 1 in table states_2017. Not sure how to amend your solution to include this.

Comment: It means that inside the query, I somehow need to provide the right "year" number: SELECT ... FROM states_'YEAR'. Any idea how to populate a variable inside the query?